# vlc activex object in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vlc

hope all of you doing well. I have small question in C#.Net. actually i am developing a application for fun on WPF which uses VLC Player activeX object for playing audio/video. I am able to play videos using this object in WPF.

**What I want to add is to little functionality in this app. So when i play Video in full-screen mode (default method provided) I want to show some info about video on the bottom screen like music channels show. it may contains images but text is sure. how i can achieve that. any help would be appreciated.**

Thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the documentation on [how to host an ActiveX control in a WPF application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx).  It has you create a Windows Forms library and uses that to create the interop and a Windows Forms control to host the control.  Then it uses WPF's ability to host a Windows Forms control.